# how to export multiple prices from virtuemart?

Tags: virtuemart

I have multiple usergroup having different price. I need to export all product data including price from the store. Can anybody help how it works in virtuemart 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component "CSV Improved" to do this task.

1. Download csvimproved.com ( free version )
2. Menu process > Choose default layout "Example Virtuemart Product export" > click in "Load"
3. At "Options" Tab, Select the shopper group as you wish
4. Click in button Save as New, put a new name
5. After that, just click in Process button in top, this will export all product prices in .csv format.

Comment: In this way one can not get the data at a time. we have to export for each shopper group individually.